# Multiplication of time complexity?

Tags: time-complexity

I understand that when you multiply two time complexities, you just multiply them as usual, for example a time complexity of `n log n` multiplied by the time complexity of `n` will give you a time complexity of `(n^2) log n`.

But where do bounds come into play? So if `n log n` was upper bound and `n` was upper bound too, what kind of bound would the product of them be? And what would it be for other combinations of lower bound upper bound and tightly bound? (For example, upperbound x tightly bound, upperbound x lowerbound and tightly bound x lowerbound.)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would _GUESS_ complexities of the same type (upper and upper or lower and lower) would multiply just like your first example. Upperbound X Lowerbound sounds like adding apples and oranges to me.

Comment: Yeah I've tried thinking about multiplying time complexities of different bounds in my head but I just cant comprehend it haha.

Comment: How I interpret multiplying complexities of different bounds I think "We're going to consider a best case scenario for our outer function and then we're going to consider the worst case scenario for our inner function" which would yield some not particularly helpful complexity between best and worst. If you want the average complexity I'd recommend sticking to your average complexity (which is of _one_ complexity class). Be aware, I can't swear to any of this! Its just my best guess! (:

Comment: Yeah I couldn't agree more. Unfortunately, these kinds of questions are going to be asked of me in exams. And I'm very confused at the moment.

Comment: Remember the text book is your friend! If the text book contradicts what I suggest, I'd definitely go with the text book!

Comment: @clay go back to tthe definition of big-O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if n log n was upper bound and n was upper bound too, what kind of bound would the product of them be?

An upper bound. See any good textbook answer for the formal analysis; the intuitive meaning of multiplying these two upper bounds is "if you have to do at most *n* lg *n* operations of cost at most *n* each, then you perform at most *n*² lg *n* work".

> upperbound × tightly bound

A tight bound is both an upper bound and a lower bound, so this is an upper bound.

> tightly bound × lowerbound

... and by the same reasoning, this is a lower bound.

> upperbound × lowerbound

No general rule. Suppose you have perform *at least n*² operations at most *n* times. That could be no work at all, or an exponential amount, or anything larger.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pure math question:

`f(x)` is `O(g(x))` if and only if there exists `M`, `x0` such that `|f(x)| <= M*|g(x)|` for all `x > x0`.  You'll see this in most elementary complexity books.

So suppose `f(x)` is `O(F(x))` and `g(x)` is `O(G(x))`.  Then `|f(x)| <= M_f * |F(x)|` for all `x > x0F` and `|g(x)| <= M_g * |G(x)|` for all `x > x0G`.

`|f(x) * g(x)| = |f(x)| * |g(x)| <= M_f * M_g * |F(x)| * |G(x)|` for all `x > max(x0F, x0G)` so `f(x) * g(x)` is `O(F(x) * G(x))` and the complexities do multiply (Write `M = M_f * M_g` and `x0 = max(x0f, x0g)` applied to the definition of big-O)

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, I chose the other answer because I understand it better.